# java Component's getSize() returning negative values

Tags: java, swing, thread-safety, awt

I have a funny situation in which intermittently I get negative values from calling a JLabel's method getSize(). I want to resize a JLabel to grab the maximum space possible but very often I get it upside down like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682364/java-upside-down-text-bug-or-feature). It seems that an instant after acquiring that negative value the right one is available.
I am almost sure that this is a thread race problem caused by my bad GUI/logic thread architecture, however, I noticed that if I remove [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709061/gridbaglayout-weighty-alignment) workaround that I made to the parent JPanel, the problem disappears.

I already tried adding a synchronized block while doing the value assignment, I did jlabel.verify() before but nothing helped. Unfortunately, I really need to keep the workaround I mentioned.

I would appreciate any guidance to solve this problem, thanks in advance.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAmTy.png]

Comment: That image doesn't help. We have no idea what you code is doing. Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `It seems that an instant after acquiring that negative value the right one is available.` Change the `if` to a `while` and you're set ahahahahaha... (But no you should probably fix the cause not the effect)

Comment: Allright, I'll update as soon as I have the MCVE, thanks!

Comment: *"I get negative values from calling a JLabel's method getSize()."*  I've had to call for the preferred size of a `JLabel` about 2 or 3 times in my Java coding since Swing was introduced.  I've had to call the size ***..never!***  Why do you think you need to call it?

Comment: I've found it to be relatively common for components to return sizes <= 0 when they are new. Component sizes are basically meaningless until they are both added to a container and set to be visible.

Comment: I have tried to generate a simplified scenario where this problem is reproduced but I haven't achieved it. However, I noticed something.
Currently I set the size of the JFrame with the following statement:
"setExtendedState( getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );", it looks like that might be the root of the problem, when I specifically set the preferred size like: "setExtendedState( this.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
  setVisible(true);
  setPreferredSize(getSize());" it works without any problem. Does this seem like a neat solution? Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

The only way something like this can happen is if another process is changing  jlabel between the time componentWidth variable was assigned and the time you are reading its value. A likely scenario is that jlabel's initialization is happening in a background thread, and was not complete when you assigned the componentWidth variable.

Comment: I don't think that any other process is changing the label's size right before I get the value, I go more with the not-initialized-crazy value. It is possible that when I call pack(), since there is no preferred size, it has to calculate it and it sometimes finishes a bit after I update the label. If I set specifically the preferred size this problem is solved, more details on the comments above. What do you think about this?

Comment: Yes, your theory is possible. The main point is that _we know for sure_ that some background process is changing the value.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly is causing the problem, but I solved it by specifically setting the preferred size (remember that most of my content returns 0, 0 as preferred size), before I only called:

```
setExtendedState( this.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
```

now:

```
    setExtendedState( this.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
    setPreferredSize(getSize());

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    setPreferredSize(getSize()); // Update to current size
    super.paint(g);
}
```